# How to use matlab in android application

Tags: android, matlab

I want to make an Android application that recognizes text from image, the code is available in Matlab. So how to execute that code in an Android application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would require installing MATLAB runtime on Android. The MATLAB runtime is not compatible with Android [unfortunately](http://uk.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/previous_releases.html). Three possible solutions :

1. Use MATLAB Coder to generate standalone C/C++ code. Then compile that for Android and call it from your app.
2. Have the MATLAB code run in a server. Your Android app will have to send an image to the server and the server would reply with the recognized text.
3. Reimplement your MATLAB code in Java so that it runs on Android

Comment: MATLAB Coder offers the option to generate C or C++ code. Any C code I've seen generated this way will compile with a C++ compiler and work fine. But I don't think any of that is important for this particular question.

Comment: Hi @Manos Nikolaidis. Can you provide more details on solution #2 (Have the MATLAB code run in a server. Your Android app will have to send an image to the server and the server would reply with the recognized text.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MATLAB, you can use '[MATLAB Support Package for Android Sensors](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47618-matlab-support-package-for-android-sensors)'

If you are using Simulink, you can use '[Simulink Support Package for Samsung GALAXY Android device](http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/android-programming-simulink.html)'. This product allows you to create Android apps directly from Simulink models.

If i am not wrong, both the above products are available free of charge. You just need base MATLAB and/or Simulink to use them.